# Mongoose findOneAndUpdate not working if I dont specify the field to update

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, hapi.js

I currently have the following mongoose function in a hapi.js api call

```
    server.route({
    method: "PUT",
    path:"/api/blockinfo/{hash}",
    handler: async (request, h) => {
        try{
            var jsonPayload = JSON.parse(request.payload)
            console.log(jsonPayload)
            var result = await BlockModel.findOneAndUpdate(request.params.hash, {$set: { height : jsonPayload[Object.keys(jsonPayload)[0]]}},  {new: true});
            return h.response(result);
        }catch{

            return h.response(error).code(500);
        }
    }
})
```

Its goal is basically to update a value using a `PUT`. In the case above, it will update the field height, and it will work just fine.

But what if I want to update an arbitrary field?

For example my object format is the following:

```
{"_id":"5cca9f15b1b535292eb4e468", "hash":"d6e0fdb404cb9779a34894b4809f492f1390216ef9d2dc0f2ec91f95cbfa89c9", "height":301651, "size":883, "time":1556782336, "__v":0}
```

In the case above I updated the height value using the `$set`, but what if I decide to input 2 random fields to update, for example, size and time.

This would be my put in postman:

```
{
    "size": 300,
    "time": 2
}
```

Well obviously it wont work in the code above because those fields are missing in the set.

SO how do i make that set to recognize automatically whatever it needs to update?

I tried to simplify it with the following code but it wont update anything

```
    server.route({
    method: "PUT",
    path:"/api/blockinfo/{hash}",
    handler: async (request, h) => {
        try{
            var result = await BlockModel.findOneAndUpdate(request.params.hash, request.payload,  {new: true});
            return h.response(result);
        }catch{

            return h.response(error).code(500);
        }
    }
})
```

Schema

```
const BlockModel = Mongoose.model("blocks", {
  hash: String,
  height: Number,
  size: Number,
  time: Number
});
```

Comment: Solved : SInce we are updating a JSON, the payload must be in JSON format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
handler: async (request, h) => {
        try{
            var result = await BlockModel.findOneAndUpdate(request.params.hash, JSON.parse(request.payload ),  {new: true});
            return h.response(result);
        }catch{

            return h.response(error).code(500);
        }
    }
```

SInce we are updating a JSON, the payload must be in JSON format

Answer (score 1):

Problem is with your `hash` key. First parameter/argument in `findOneAndUpdate` function should be the `key` `value` pair. And here you are directly putting the `key`.

So it should be

```
handler: async (request, h) => {
  try {
    const { hash } = request.params
    var result = await BlockModel.findOneAndUpdate({ hash }, request.payload,  { new: true })
    return h.response(result)
  } catch (err) {
    return h.response(error).code(500)
  }
}
```

Update:

You are defining mongoose model in incorrect way. Schema is not just an object. It should be mongoose object. Something like this

```
const schema = new Mongoose.Schema({
  hash: String,
  height: Number,
  size: Number,
  time: Number
})

export default Mongoose.model("blocks", schema)
```

Comment: I dont think thats the issue. I have other api calls like DELETE one (findOneAndDelete) , and im using ```request.params.hash.toString()``` , to identify the object , If i try to implement it in my current PUT, it wont work anyway. Your answer will log ```{ hash:
   'd6e0fdb404cb9779a34894b4809f492f1390216ef9d2dc0f2ec91f95cbfa89c9' }``` and wont update anything. It returns an error. And my alternative ```request.params.hash.toString()``` returns ```d6e0fdb404cb9779a34894b4809f492f1390216ef9d2dc0f2ec91f95cbfa89c9``` and wont update anything, despite of using it in the delete method just fine

Comment: Theres not really any error, it just returns the same object without any change

Comment: Could you post your schema

Comment: I use a model
```const BlockModel = Mongoose.model('blocks', {        //modelo blocks de la bd
    hash: String,
    height: Number,
    size: Number,
    time: Number
})```

Comment: @mouchin777 Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have not added `$set` in your simplified code, adding that it should work.
Send `payload` as an object with the required fields.

```
server.route({
    method: "PUT",
    path:"/api/blockinfo/{hash}",
    handler: async (request, h) => {
        try{
            var result = await BlockModel.findOneAndUpdate(request.params.hash, { $set: request.payload } ,  {new: true});
            return h.response(result);
        }catch{

            return h.response(error).code(500);
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: That doesnt seem to be the issue, it will return an error.

Comment: Theres not really any error message, it just gets caught by the 500 error code

```{
    "statusCode": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "message": "An internal server error occurred"
}```

Comment: can you post your postman object? in question you missed `:` after `"time"`

Comment: ```
{
 "size": 300,
 "time" : 2
}
```
, i send it with a PUT . The missed : is not the issue i misstyped it in the q